# Android studio SQLite database data retrieval for specific entires

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So I am making an itinerary type application where the user makes an itinerary and has multiple entries in one itinerary. So i need to be able to retrieve all the data from one itinerary. For example if the Itinerary is called Monday, and the user selected that one to view, i would want all the data from that. I've done this by having the ItineraryName, e.g. Monday, be passed through to another activity, which works but i've only seen through print statements to check the value has passed through correctly.

Currently i can view the data for a specific Itinerary, e.g. Monday, only if i manually input into the selection args variable(see below) but if i try pass it by a variable it wont work and i get an error, also i have tried putting "%" + ItineraryName + "%" into the selection args but i am presented with a blank activity. Error for just variable:

Process: com.example.chiraag.qavel, PID: 10198
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chiraag.qavel/com.example.chiraag.qavel.ItineraryDetails}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:294)
                                                       at com.example.chiraag.qavel.DBManager.Query(DBManager.java:101)
                                                       at com.example.chiraag.qavel.ItineraryDetails.loadItinerary(ItineraryDetails.java:47)
                                                       at com.example.chiraag.qavel.ItineraryDetails.onCreate(ItineraryDetails.java:34)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Code for ItineraryDetails:

```
public class ItineraryDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

DBManager db;
myAdapter myAdapter;
ListView ls;
private String ItineraryName;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_itinerary_details);

    db = new DBManager(this);
    ls = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ItineraryDetails_listview);

   loadItinerary();

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

  ItineraryName = bundle.getString("Name");
    System.out.println("Name " + ItineraryName);

}

public void loadItinerary(){
    ArrayList<Adapter> listData = new ArrayList<Adapter>();
    listData.clear();
    String []selectionargs = {ItineraryName};
    Cursor cursor = db.Query("Itinerary",null, "ItineraryName like ?", selectionargs , DBManager.ColId);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            listData.add(new Adapter(
                    null
                    , cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColName))
                    , cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColLocation))
                    , null
                    , null
                    , null
                    ,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColTime))
                    ,null,null, null, null
                    ,null
                    ,null));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    myAdapter = new myAdapter(listData);
    ls.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}

class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<Adapter> listItem;
    Adapter ac;
    public myAdapter(ArrayList<Adapter> listItem) {
        this.listItem = listItem;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        LayoutInflater myInflator = getLayoutInflater();
        final View myView = myInflator.inflate(R.layout.list_items_itinerary_details, null);

        ac = listItem.get(position);

        TextView ItineraryName = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tvItineraryDetailsEntryName);
        ItineraryName.setText(ac.Name);

        TextView ItineraryLocation = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tvItineraryDetailsEntryLocation);
        ItineraryLocation.setText(ac.Location);

        TextView ItineraryTime = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.tvItineraryDetailsEntryTime);
        ItineraryTime.setText(ac.Time);

        return myView;
    }
}
}
```

Code for DBManager:

```
public class DBManager  {

private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;
static final String ColId = "ID";
static final String DBName = "InternalDB";
static final String TableName = "BookmarkAttraction";
static final String TableName2 = "BookmarkTransport";
static final String TableName3 = "Itinerary";
static final String ColItineraryName = "ItineraryName";
static final String ColDate = "Date";
static final String ColType = "Type";
static final String ColName = "Name";
static final String ColLocation = "Location";
static final String ColOpening = "OpeningTime";
static final String ColClosing = "ClosingTime";
static final String ColNearbyStop = "NerbyStop1";


static final String ColTime = "Time";
static final String ColNextStop = "NextStop";
static final String ColPhoneNumber = "PhoneNumber";

static final int DBVersion = 1;

static final String CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TableName + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + ColType+ " TEXT," +
        ColName+ " TEXT," + ColLocation+ " TEXT," + ColOpening+ " TEXT," +ColClosing+ " TEXT," + ColNearbyStop+ " TEXT);";

static  final String CreateTabe2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +TableName2 + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + ColType + " TEXT,"
        + ColName + " TEXT,"
        + ColLocation + " TEXT,"
        + ColTime+ " TEXT,"
        + ColNextStop + " TEXT,"
        + ColPhoneNumber + " TEXT);";

static final String CreateTable3 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TableName3 + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + ColItineraryName + " TEXT,"
        + ColDate + " TEXT," + ColName + " TEXT," + ColLocation + " TEXT," + ColTime + " TEXT);";


static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    Context context;

    DBHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DBName, null, DBVersion);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Toast.makeText(context,DBName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.execSQL(CreateTable);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Table is created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.execSQL(CreateTabe2);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Transport table created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.execSQL(CreateTable3);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Itin table created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TableName);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TableName2);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TableName3);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}


public DBManager(Context context){
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(context);
    sqlDB = db.getWritableDatabase();
}

public long Insert(String tablename,ContentValues values){
    long ID =  sqlDB.insert(tablename,"",values);
    return ID;
}

public Cursor Query(String tablename, String [] projection, String selection, String [] selectionArgs, String sortOrder){
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    qb.setTables(tablename);
    Cursor cursor = qb.query(sqlDB,projection, selection, selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
    return cursor;
}

public int Delete(String tablename,String selection, String[] selectionArgs){
    int count = sqlDB.delete(tablename,selection,selectionArgs);
    return count;
}
}
```

The error points to my query method in my DBManager class, I may have structured it wrong, i'm not sure because i first created it to retrieve all data from a table. Any help with this would be great thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to bind the variable ItineraryName before it's been defined. You call loadItinerary before you define ItineraryName but try to use it in the query were you create your cursor. I think this is causing the error you're seeing

Comment: Thank you that did work, don't know how i didn't see that